# How to get values from the selected item in a list view?

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my code so far. This is working but it only shows the very first value I have in the listView , not the selecting item by the user. Please halp me with this. This is really important.

```
        unitListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

          unitListView.setOnItemClickListener(new   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

                  // selected item
                 TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName);

                 String name=t1.getText().toString();

          //    String a= (String) unitListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                       // touchpressed=position;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Item :" +name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName); could you please try TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName);

Comment: Great. An upvote would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Show your `getView(...)`, do you use viewholder in it?

Answer (score 0):

View is just to show some values on UI. If you want to get real values use `position` to get a value from your `ListAdapter`.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    YourItemClass item = (YourItemClass)listAdapter.getItem(position);
    //[...]
}
```

Other way is to get `ListAdapter` from your `unitListView` directly:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Object item = unitListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    //[...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as follows and try ;

```
      unitListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
      unitListView.setOnItemClickListener(new   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

             TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName);
             String name=String.valuesOf(position);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Item :" +name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Once I changed like TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName); it is working! Thank you for your help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName);`

By

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName);
```